# jQuery.get() method doesn't want to work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, get

I am trying to load WalkScore Map into one of div's on the page. For some reason my code works only if I `alert()` something right after `$.get()` method. Have no idea why.

Can someone suggest something? Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery - Ajax dynamic content loading</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function loadWalkScore() 
{
    $.get("http://www.walkscore.com/tile/show-tile.php?wsid=567f19156a706dddb8a799630d85467e",null,null,"script");
    alert("hello");
}

</script>
```

```
<div id="contentArea" style="margin: 20px 0px 10px 10px; border: 1px solid #CCC;">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var ws_lat = "40.710318";
    var ws_lon = "-74.016553";
    var ws_width = "630";
    loadWalkScore();
</script>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this, to make the call when the DOM is ready.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
$.get("http://www.walkscore.com/tile/show-tile.php?wsid=567f19156a706dddb8a799630d85467e",null,null,"script");
});
</script>
```

Put this block after your first `<script>` element.

Comment: Hi Peter,

It still doesn't work for me. The page is loading indefinitely in FF 3 and IExplorer 8. 

I also tried using $(document).ready(function(), see code below:

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var ws_lat = "40.710318";
  var ws_lon = "-74.016553";
  var ws_width = "630";
  $.get("http://www.walkscore.com/tile/show-tile.php?wsid=567f19156a706dddb8a799630d85467e",null,null,"script");
 });
 </script>

Answer (score 0):

For me is working. I had to change the wsid for my domain. I've checked the get request using Firebug and I get a javascript as a response. At the begining I was getting an error because I was using you wsid and it seems that for each calling sides they generate a new one. Try to see if your wsid is the correct one.

Comment: Hello Elzo,

What browsers do you use (except FF)? 

I uploaded two examples here:

http://websvit.com/tabs/no-alert.html  // doesn't work

http://websvit.com/tabs/with-alert.html  // works here

Comment: in FF is working, even the one that you say is not. If is a browser issue I dont think is jQuery related.